# Disable Gestures through registry

Tags: windows, gesture, regedit

On windows, I want to disabe gestures through Settings->touchpad->three-finger/four-finger gestures works immediately.

I noticed that when setting changed, registry value changed on the same time:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\ThreeFingerSlideEnabled
```

But when I try to modify the registry value by regedit.exe, it's not working without explorer.exe restart.

I try to send message WM_SETTINGCHANGE after modify registry, not work either.

```
PDWORD_PTR lpdwResult = 0;
SendMessageTimeoutA(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, NULL, (LPARAM)"Environment", SMTO_NORMAL, 2000, lpdwResult);
```

Is there any way to disable gestures without restarting the explorer.?

Comment: WM_SETTINGCHANGE is probably correct but "Environment" is not, create a window and wait for the message and dump the string...

Comment: @Anders I already try it. And receive a message named: "SettingsCacheChangeMessage". When I try to send it myself, it's not work either. So I think there may have something else that we missed.